# One div pushing another over

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float a div (next > previous < links) (#nextprev) to the right of an already right-floated div (#rightcontent). At the moment the #nextprev div is pushing the #rightcontent div into the centre of the page - see here...

http://alexch.net/kblondel/project-01a.html

... but ideally I'd like to keep the #rightcontent div positioned as it was previously...

http://alexch.net/kblondel/project-01.html

There's a right margin on #rightcontent which I guess is making this div get pushed to the left. I really want the #nextprev to ignore this margin in this instance and sit next to #rightcontent.

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just take out the margin-right on `#contentright`?

Comment: Please provide code or reproduce in a jsfiddle.net, otherwise the links will be useless for future readers of the question once they are fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @helion3 mentions in the comment above, removing the right margin on #contentright is the right idea. To match the old one `margin-right: 30px` will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the extra div that is added:

```
<div id="nextprev">next &gt;<br>&lt; prev</div>
```

Update CSS of  #contentright and take out margin-right

```
#contentright {
    float: right;   
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
    width: 420px;
}
```